# What does 0j mean in cmath?

Tags: python, cmath

I am learning about the cmath module but I cannot interpret the terms
when solving quadratic equations. What is 0j? What does 0j symbolise?

```
import cmath

a = 1
b = 8
c = 16

discriminant = (b**2)-(4*a*c)
print(discriminant)


solution_1 = (-b-cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)
solution_2 = (-b+cmath.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a)

print(solution_1, solution_2)
```

```
Output:
0
(-4+0j) (-4+0j)
```

Comment: Alright why are you using `cmath` module in the first place (instead of just `math` because in this case the answer is real)? They should cover it in the documentation.

Comment: I was searching for ways to do maths in python. I came accross it in a documentation but the documentation had no information about the "0j" stuff or I may have missed it.

Comment: Thank you so much who ever sent the link